# iPhone modal view and navigation view question

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating an iPhone app and I have a problem when using navigation view controller and modal view.

Basically, the main UI of the app is an Tabbar view, but before that the app would pop up a navigation view for user to sign in/up. The pop up is implemented as a modal view.

In the navigation view controller, the root view is sign in page as a table view programmatically created without nib file.

The problem is that when the navigation view pop up, only the title bar("sign in") show up, the table view of sign in does not.

What's the possible reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a navigation controller? You could add the view of your login controller to the window in the app delegate and after successful login you could exchange it with the tabbar controller.

Comment: Can you post some code of your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Nick: The navigation controller is for sign in and sign up

Comment: Adarsh: the rootview of the navigation view controller is a table view, I added it in the interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you haven't initialized the UITableViewController with a non CGRectZero size. Try to initialize it with initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 440.0f)

Comment: I set up the root view of the navigation controller in Interface Builder, do I still need to initialize the table view?

Comment: No, if you did it with IB it should be there. Try changing the backgroundColor of the tableView to see if it really exists.

Comment: I figured this out. For some reason, I need to subclass a UITableViewController, not just implement the delegate UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. Thanks anyway.